# How to change the background color of slider ( type = "range")

Tags: css, html

I am using type = "range" for slider. Problem is my background div is black and hence nothing is visible .. only the dot is visible and i am able to click and slide it.

Any idea how to change it ?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? What Browser are you using? Because this one in Chrome looks fine [Slider jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hNJqQ/)

Comment: Your fiddle is also not looking fine at my end on Chrome. What is the color of your slider ?

Comment: Both fiddles look fine to me in Chrome and Opera.  The slider and the bar are both clearly visible.

Comment: Strange enough .. they look fine on windows ( chrome ) but not on Mac ( chrome , opera ).